# find the optimal solution in python

Tags: python, optimization, global

I have this formula:

1 - e^(log(0.5) * (x / beta) ^ alpha )

with alpha and beta that are my variable that I have to find.
x is a bunch of images (my data) and I can compare that formula's output with the ground truth that comes from a user test. Basically I can generate a loss function that I would like to minimize. For finding the best alpha and beta I tried to use tensorflow but gradient descent and other optimizers appear to fail as that function is not convex (I try different initial conditions). Is there a global optimization tool in python that I can use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [NLopt](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which has some global optimizers, e.g. DIRECT (download at [gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#nlopt)). Or there is scipy's [basinhopping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html#scipy.optimize.basinhopping). Another nice solution is [NOMAD](https://www.gerad.ca/nomad/), a very good black box optimizier. It also has a Python interface, but it is not that user friendly and intuitive.

You can find other hints on local and global optimization in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52438791/7919597) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61495132/7919597).