# scipy.optimize get's trapped in local minima. What can I do?

Tags: python, scipy, spyder, minimization

```
 from numpy import *; from scipy.optimize import *; from math import *
def f(X):
    x=X[0];    y=X[1]
    return x**4-3.5*x**3-2*x**2+12*x+y**2-2*y

bnds = ((1,5), (0, 2))
min_test = minimize(f,[1,0.1], bounds = bnds); 
print(min_test.x)
```

My function `f(X)`has a local minima at `x=2.557, y=1` which I should be able to find.

The code showed above will only give result where `x=1`. I have tried with different tolerance and alle three method: L-BFGS-B, TNC and SLSQP.
This is the thread I have been looking at so far:
[Scipy.optimize: how to restrict argument values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244527/scipy-optimize-how-to-restrict-argument-values)

How can I fix this?

I am using Spyder(Python 3.6).

[image]

Comment: `print(f([2557, 1])) = 42690172880760.5`, I would not call this a local minimum...

Comment: `f([1, 1]) = 6.5`

Comment: Sorry, I meant 2.557. I have edited

Comment: Try a  [global optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_optimization) method instead. SciPy offers [some of them](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#global-optimization).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just encounterd the problem with local optimization: it strongly depends on the start (initial) values you pass in. If you supply `[2, 1]` it will find the correct minima.

Common solutions are:

- use your optimization in a loop with random starting points inside your boundaries

  ```
  import numpy as np
  from numpy import *; from scipy.optimize import *; from math import *

  def f(X):
      x=X[0];    y=X[1]
      return x**4-3.5*x**3-2*x**2+12*x+y**2-2*y

  bnds = ((1,3), (0, 2))

  for i in range(100):

      x_init = np.random.uniform(low=bnds[0][0], high=bnds[0][1])
      y_init = np.random.uniform(low=bnds[1][0], high=bnds[1][1])

      min_test = minimize(f,[x_init, y_init], bounds = bnds)

      print(min_test.x, min_test.fun)
  ```
- use an algorithm that can break free of local minima, I can recommend scipy's `basinhopping()`
- use a global optimization algorithm and use it's result as initial value for a local algorithm. Recommendations are NLopt's `DIRECT` or the MADS algorithms (e.g. `NOMAD`). There is also another one in scipy, `shgo`, that I have no tried yet.

Comment: Thank you. I have actually much problems with scipy.minimize when functions gets long and complicated. Can you recommend alternatives?

Comment: What do you mean with long and complicated? There are some other optimization modules, e.g. `nlopt`. But they all will use your long and complicated function. In the end the methods available in scipy are fine for a large variety of problems.

Answer (score 6):

Try `scipy.optimize.basinhopping`. It simply just repeat your minimize procedure multiple times and get multiple local minimums. The minimal one is the global minimum.

```
minimizer_kwargs = {"method": "L-BFGS-B"}
res=optimize.basinhopping(nethedge,guess,niter=100,minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs)
```