# Constrained optimization stuck in local minima, but the minima isn't strict. Any alternatives to global optimization?

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, nonlinear-optimization

I have an objective function, with non-linear inequality constraints, which I am currently minimizing with `scipy.minimize`. However, I have an example right now that the minimizer is unable to solve, due to the fact that the objective has a local minima, that the solver gets stuck in.

The local minima is however not a strict minima, but rather just a flat plateau. Are there any local constrained optimization solver able to handle such cases, or do I have to move to a global solver?

My own intuition tells me that a local solver should be sufficient, since it shouldn't actually be possible to be 'stuck' in this local minima. But of course I can understand why my current solvers aren't working since all they try is to take small steps along each free parameter and find that the value stays the same.

So far I have looked at `scipy.optimize` to see whether it had any settings for keep searching to ensure that any minima is truly a strict minima, but it doesn't seem to be the case, at least not for the solvers that allow nonlinear constraints.

I have also looked at similar questions previously posted like: [scipy.optimize get's trapped in local minima. What can I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52438263/scipy-optimize-gets-trapped-in-local-minima-what-can-i-do), but none of the questions I found was dealing with non-strict minima.

I am considering to try scipy's `basinhopping` global optimization though I am unsure whether that will work well.